# How to refresh an html page using ajax in Django?

Tags: html, django, ajax

I know this question has been asked several times, but I cannot find a solution.

I cannot connect the method output in views with html page.

**views**

```
def save_form(request):
    if request.method == 'POST' and 'save' in request.POST:
        lsection = [5]
        print("calculate method runs...")
        return JsonResponse({'lsection':lsection})
```

"calculate method runs..." is printed only when I do not use ajax.

**html**

```
<form method="post" name="nameForm" id="idForm" 
action = "/project/save/" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {% csrf_token %}

...

<input type="submit" name="save" value="Save">
</form>
```

**ajax**

```
var frm = $('#idForm');
frm.submit(function (e) {

    e.preventDefault();

    $.ajax({
        type: frm.attr('save_form'),
        url: frm.attr('/project/save/'),
        //data: frm.serialize(), // I tried this as well
        data: {},
        success: function (data) {
            alert(data)
        },
        error: function (data) {
            alert("ajax fails")
        },
    });
});
```

**Question:**

I do not get lsection list on html, I try alert(data) I get an empty html.
How can I get lsection on html?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need attribute's values:

```
type: frm.attr('method'),
url: frm.attr('action'),
```

Correct code:

```
$.ajax({
        type: frm.attr('method'),
        url: frm.attr('action'),
        data: frm.serialize(),
        success: function (data) {
            alert(data)
        },
        error: function (data) {
            alert("ajax fails")
        }
    });
```

[.attr](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/html_attr.asp)

Answer (score 0):

While receiving JSON response in ajax success you used data.

to show the lsection.

```
alert(data.lsection)
```

update alert like above

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it alerts: "undefined", since as I wrote in the question, the method does not run. However without the ajax it runs perfectly. why?

Comment: remove the action from form and try to use this below ajax code 

$.ajax({
           url : '/project/save/',
           method : 'post',
           data : $(this).serialize(),
           success: function(data){
            alert(data.lsection)
             }
             error: function (data) {
                alert("ajax fails")
             },
       });

Comment: I thin you broke the connection with the method. It redirects to a page with only: {"lsection": [5]}